# API to register verified domain with Google cloud project to subscribe for pub/sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm looking for a way to create push subscription to a pub/sub topic fully from code. I managed to verify domain with domain verification api, but I cannot find an api to register domain with a project. The only way described here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/advanced#register is with an interactive use of a console.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a push subscriber from code using the [create subscription API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create) (or [GRPC version](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber)). When the PushConfig parameter is provided, where you specify the push endpoint, the subscription is set up as a push subscription.